# Matrix existence..

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How to prove that for any matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ ($m\geq n$) such that $rank(A)=r$ there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ and an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that,
\begin{align*}
A=U\Gamma P^{-1},
\end{align*}
where,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\Gamma=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\textrm{diag}(\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_r)&0\\ 0&0
\end{array}\right),
\end{align*}
and,
\begin{align*}
\gamma_i=\sqrt{p_i^TA^TAp_i},\ i=1, \ldots, r.
\end{align*}
If those matrices indeed exist I can prove the equality for $\gamma_i$ using SVD, but I wasn't manage to show they really exist..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. However, if you are *not* questioning the existence of SVD, then the SVD of $A$ already gives you the required decomposition, doesn't it?

Comment: I thought that too @user1551 but it would be strange not to ask for proving the SVD decomposition directly, this question is a bit strange..

Comment: @Dion: I don't understand. If you are looking for a proof of the existence of SVD, you may look up any popular reference book. See, e.g. sec. 2.5 of Golub and van Loan's [Matrix Computations](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA69&hl=zh-TW&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) or sec. 7.3 of Horn and Johnson's [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&pg=PA411&hl=zh-TW&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). If the existence of SVD is not the question, why can't you just apply it?

Comment: user1551 thanks for the Help, I'll look it up!